# How to record webcam output locally while the video is also streamed in a video conference?

Tags: mac

When I record video interviews over Hangouts / Skype / Zoom, I often ask the guest to record the audio locally using QuickTime Player, then get them to send me the audio file afterwards. I also record the video conference "in the cloud" using Google Hangouts record feature.
This means I get better quality audio that I can resync afterwards.

Is there a good way to do the same thing with video as I do with audio on a Mac? When I try to record their webcam in Quicktime Player, it stops the video stream working.

How can I let the guest record their webcam output while at the same time the webcam is streamed to Hangouts?

Comment: When you say `When I try to ... video stream working.`, how are you recording their webcam with QT? Via the screen record utility?

Comment: I open Quicktime, click New Movie Recording, choose their webcam, hit record.

Comment: And you do this on their computer? In that case I think I understand the problem: the webcam can only send its recording to 1 app at a time, when you choose the webcam in Quicktime, the webcam switches its signal from Hangouts to Quicktime. You need some kind of software that can reroute/duplicate the webcam signal such that it goes both to quicktime and to hangouts (something similar to a video version of [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/).

Comment: yes - I'm wondering whether such a thing exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem interpretation

I'm interpreting the issue you're having as follows:

On the computer of the guest you want to record the audio and video stream from one or more devices. The same streams need to be available to the online meeting software (Skype/Zoom/Hangouts).

The issue you're running into with Quicktime is that a webcam can (often) only supply it's video stream to one program at a time. It first supplies it to Hangouts, but when you ask Quicktime to record, it switches the stream to Quicktime, stopping the video stream to Hangouts.

You need some way of "splitting" the signal.

#### Possible solution

You can use [OSB Studio](https://obsproject.com/) to achieve what you want. It allows you to record and stream the webcam video at the same time, the meeting software can then use OBS (not your webcam) as the video input device.

Rough steps are:

1. Install OBS Studio
2. In the sources panel, add a new "Video Capture Device":
   [image]
3. In the properties window that pops up, select the webcam you want to use in the "Device" dropdown, leave the rest of the settings at their default:
   [image]
4. Now OBS studio should show you what the webcam is seeing. You can move/scale the image and apply effects or corrections as needed.
5. Now you can let OBS start a "virtual camera". This will provide the video stream you see in the OBS screen as if it is coming from a "webcam" named "OBS Virtual Camera":
   [image]
6. In the meeting software, go to the device settings and select "OBS Virtual Camera" (screenshot shows Teams as an example):
   [image]
7. In OBS Studio you can now turn on the recording, it will record the webcam (and any other sources you've added in step 2):
   [image]
8. When you start your online meeting, the meeting software will use "OBS Virtual Camera" as the camera. OBS Studio will record the webcam output in the background.

I've described the steps for the video part, but I imagine you can do something similar with the audio such that you get a synced recording right away. Then you don't need to re-sync the Quicktime recorded audio with the OBS recorded video.

Comment: Great answer, I hadn't thought of that... The trouble is the people I'm recording are often not very technical!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with OBS, but I believe you can store configurations such that you only need to set steps 2-4 once after which you can load the configuration on different machines. However, it still requires the installation of OBS and the reconfiguration of the video conferencing software.